# Youtube video in html5 not showing video that i choose

Tags: html, youtube

I've checked all the questions and answers in stackoverflow but I can solve my problem.
I'm trying to embed a youtube video in my website(on desktop, static) but it only shows me the video that is in the w3cschool example or doesn't show me anything(not even a blank box).

This is my code but for some reason it's not showing the video I choose on Youtube and yes I did use the embedded code from youtube.

```
<iframe width="300" height="300" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/yiboIS-f27Q?rel=0?html5=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

I just had to add http: in front of // in the youtube url.

Answer found from the answer of Nick R in the question 
Youtube embeded video not working in all my browsers: FireFox, IE and Chrome